# Test django application: need to delete a row in postgres, and then recover

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a `Django` application which is interacting with `postgres`. To test application I want to delete several rows from a table and see the outcome of it on the retrieved data (queries are pretty complex, so to just see whether everything is good is hard otherwise). Whats the best practice to approach such a case? Most straightforward is to write down all of the data for the deleted rows, delete rows, test app, then reinsert the rows, but I feel like its too manual, time consuming and not how it should be done. Besides there is a small chance of missing something out and/or sometimes the model can't be easily deleted without deleting other model rows when they are related by a foreign key.

Comment: You should write tests that use a test database and dummy data. Take a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/overview/). If you don't want to write tests the best thing would be to create a database backup and restoring it after deleting things, will be better than doing it manually

Comment: Is there any trick to do it easier? Thats what I am looking for.

Comment: You could use fixtures: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/initial-data/), and once you want to empty your tables use django shell and remove the data